# What is the word to describe that something is overly hyped?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word to describe that something is overly-hyped?

I mean something like *buzzword* or *buzzphrase* but of course those are not adjectives.

Comment: "Overhyped" is a valid word. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overhyped

Comment: Doesn't **hyped** already include the excess you want to convey?

Comment: its not *accurate* enough. i was wondering if anyone had any other alternative words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `overhyped` would work, but chiefly for something that is actually being (actively) hyped.

`Overused` or `overexposed` are good for something that has just been used so much it has lost all of its punch.

Beyond those two, there is [cliched](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clich%C3%A9).

Comment: Wouldn't that be clichéd?

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for.. but o well

Comment: @configurator - Probably. My USA keyboard doesn't have that special accented `é` key though, and I didn't really feel like figuring out how to produce it (or more likely, finding it in another word online and copy-and-pasting it, like I did here). Anyway, since our USA keyboards don't have that key, its perfectly acceptable to just use an `e` there.

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of sounding a bit too obvious, I would be OK with the verb '[overhype](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overhype)', which I think is pretty standard in contemporary English and which Wiktionary, at least, lists as a word.  You could therefore describe something as 'overhyped'.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a [fad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fad).